# Como salvar valores de um vetor em uma database?

Tags: java, android, sql

Estou criando um app Android para o tcc. Eu tenho 3 vetores: `coorx[i]; coory[i]; busy[i]`. Esse vetor busy não é fixo, então os valores ficaram alterando de acordo com o que o usuário solicitar. Então eu teria que salvar o valor desse busy em um database. O que eu faço? Melhor eu transformar isso em um objeto com os atributos `coorx, coory, busy`? E se eu transformar, ainda nao sei como fazer a comunicação entre o database e o busy.

Comment: Você sabe como salvar um valor escalar em uma tabela? Qual a estrutura/tabelas e colunas que vai persistir essa informação?

Comment: Eu estou começando a programar agora no android, não tenho muita noção de database. Na verdade, eu so preciso de uma tabela "busy", unica que ira ficar variando entre 1 e 0 ( ocupado e vazio ); eu preciso de ficar alterando esse valor de acordo se o slot esta ou nao vazio. Minha dificuldade é : como começar uma tabela com id de 1 a 12 e com todos os busy com valor de 0. Por exemplo                                          ID     1,2,3,4,5,6....                                                                                               Busy 0,0,0,0,0,0....

Comment: Poderia então atualizar a pergunta com as informações pertinentes?